# Issue to load file from path using SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, xml, file-io

I've done a .Net Web Service Client to send a file trough it and it works smoothly; but when I use that Application from a Store Procedure from SQL Server 2005 like this:

exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'C:\folder\myapp user@domain.com Application "\192.168.1.200\folder\2012\12\file.xml"'

I get this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\\192.168.1.200\folder\2012\12\file.xml' is denied.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath) 
NULL
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding)
   at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllText(String path, Encoding encoding)
   at System.IO.File.ReadAllText(String path)
   at myapp.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: What account is your Sql Server running under?  Does this account have permission to access this file?

Answer (score 0):

```
Access to the path '\\192.168.1.200\folder\2012\12\file.xml' is denied.
```

The service account of SQL-Server has no Access this folder.
You could try to change the account(user) of the SQL-Server, or place the file there where it can be accessed.